# implementing a mad lib game using a JFileChooser and scanner

Tags: java, file, user-interface, java.util.scanner, jfilechooser

i'm having trouble writing the part of the program in the action listener method. here's what i have so far-- any help would be appreciated with an explanation as to what's being done. the assignment requires the use of a JFileChooser. i have three files. one contains nouns, one verbs, and one with a story in which the nouns and verbs must be inserted after being chosen at random.
in the story file, # are placed where nouns must go and % are placed where verbs must go. I need to take the nouns and verbs and replace the symbols with them.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MadLibApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  JButton storyButton = new JButton("SELECT STORY FILE");
  JButton verbsButton = new JButton("SELECT VERBS FILE");
  JButton nounsButton = new JButton("SELECT NOUNS FILE");
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  JTextField output = new JTextField(20);


  public static void main()
  {
     MadLibApp frame = new MadLibApp();
     frame.setBackground(Color.PINK);
     frame.setSize(300, 300);
     frame.setTitle("MAD LIB GAME");
     frame.createGUI();
     frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void createGUI()
  {
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     Container window = getContentPane();
     window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     panel.setSize(300,300);
     panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
     window.add(panel);

     storyButton.addActionListener(this);
     verbsButton.addActionListener(this);
     nounsButton.addActionListener(this);
     JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Your Mad-Lib is: ");

     JButton button = new JButton("click to play");

     panel.add(storyButton);
     panel.add(verbsButton);
     panel.add(nounsButton);
     panel.add(outputLabel);
     panel.add(output);

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     Random selectRandomVerb = new Random();
     Random selectRandomNoun = new Random();

     int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
     if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
     }



     if (e.getSource().equals(verbsButton))
     {
        try 
        { 
        File verbsFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        if (verbsFile.exists())
        {
            Scanner verbsScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(verbsFile));
            ArrayList<String> verbLines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String verbLine;
            while ((verbLine = verbsScanner.nextLine()) != null) {
                verbLines.add(verbLine);
            }
            int v = selectRandomVerb.nextInt(verbLines.size());
            String verb = verbLines.get(v);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That file does not exist.");
        }
         }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ev)
        {
        ev.printStackTrace();
       }
     }



     if (e.getSource().equals(nounsButton))
     {
        try
        {
         File nounsFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

         if (nounsFile.exists())
         {
           Scanner nounsScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(nounsFile));
           ArrayList<String> nounLines = new ArrayList<String>();
           String nounLine;
            while ((nounLine = nounsScanner.nextLine()) != null) {
                nounLines.add(nounLine);
            }
            int n = selectRandomNoun.nextInt(nounLines.size());
            String noun = nounLines.get(n);
         }
         else
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That file does not exist.");
         }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ev)
        {
         ev.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     if (e.getSource().equals(storyButton))
     {
        File storyFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try{
         if (storyFile.exists())
         {
            Scanner storyScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(storyFile));
            ArrayList<String> storyArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String element : storyArrayList) {
               if (storyScanner.nextLine() == "#")
               {

               }
            }

            for (String element : storyArrayList) {
               if (storyScanner.nextLine() == "%")
               {

               }
            }

            // output.setText();

         }
         else
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That file does not exist.");
         }
         }
         catch(FileNotFoundException ev)
        {
         ev.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
  }



}
```

Comment: what part of your code is troubling you?

Comment: thank you to the two of you who have helped so far. both posts were very helpful and easy to understand. i was having trouble figuring out how to randomly choose a line from the files

Comment: @Abby Lee Williams I've edited my answer to address your current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `Scanner` you should pass a `FileInputStream` to read the file, because if you pass `System.in` the `Scanner` will read from the console input.
Try this:

```
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(verbsFile));){

                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                String line;
                while ((line = sc.nextLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
                }
                Random rd = new Random();
                int i = rd.nextInt(lines.size());
                String verb = lines.get(i); // this is a random verb from the verbsFile

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This will work only if the verbs in the file are each on its own line.

I see you've edited your question, here is how you can write the changes to the `storyFile`:

```
     try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("storyFile"));) {
        for (String line : storyArrayList) {
            if (line.equals("#")) {
                pw.append(noun);
            } else if (line.equals("%")) {
                pw.append(verb);
            } else {
                pw.append(line);
            }

            pw.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You should close the `Scanner` after you read all the lines from the `storyFile` and make the `nouns` and `verbs` variables global. Also there are other places in your code where you create `Scanners` and leave them open. Your code will work but is not good practice to read/write files on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) Thread

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the

> JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION

```
int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
}
```

Comment: thank you very much both of you! both comments were very helpful. i'm making progress (i think) but now i'm lost with how to print the modified story into a text field. i've edited the above to show what i have so far, and i've clarified what i need to do above the code.